# Display user group of logged in user in django admin change_form.html?

Tags: python, django

How to display user group of logged in user in django admin change_form.html ? I want to display the group name of the logged in user in the change_form of a model. Eg I am able to display the user name by using {{ user }} tag. How to display {{ user.groups__name }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it directly in the template though you can try iterating over `user.groups.all()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052531/get-user-group-in-a-view provides the solution  yahoo! use the tag {{ user.groups.all.0 }}