# Django - Show/hide urls in base html dependant on user group?

Tags: python, django

I want to try and show or hide urls in my navigation page based on user group.
currently i am adding to the top of every view and sending through a value to the template and checking against that, but this doesnt seem too efficient,  also if a view does not require auth and that value is not set, will that break the template?

is there a better way to do this?
like a global.py where i could check and set then use it in any template? or something completely different altogether?

view.py

```
Authorised_user = ''
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    Authorised_user = 'IT'

@login_required
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'service/index.html', {
        'Authorised': Authorised_user,
    })
```

template.html

```
{% if Authorised == 'IT' or Authorised =='Netwworks' %}
 <a href="link">Link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. How are you determining whether the user is IT or Networks? And why can't you do that in the template?

Comment: There is no global.py, but you can write a custom context manager to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you looking for TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?

Comment: If it would be an option to handle this via Django's groups: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35977488/469111

Comment: @DanielRoseman think i got a bit mixed up in my code, i do have the user groups in django admin, i would to use those as a ref in templates

Comment: @Anoop i followed your answer and got the result i needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i do have the user groups in django admin

Based on [Get user group in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052531/get-user-group-in-a-template/35977488#35977488)

Create *user_tags.py* / *group_tags.py* at an appropriate place. e.g. *auth_extra/templatetags/user_tags.py*

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter('in_group')
def in_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load user_tags %}

{% if request.user|in_group:"IT"%}
  <a href="link">IT only link</a>
{% endif %}

{% if request.user|in_group:"Netwworks"%}
  <a href="link"> Netwworks only link</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way around this for me was https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087532/8326187.
Here you don't have to create a custom template tag.

```
  {% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == "groupname" %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create context_processors.py and create a function say

```
def foo():
   Authorised_user = ''
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
     Authorised_user = 'IT'
```

Then in setttings 
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("path_to_context_processor.foo")
this way you can use foo variable in all the templates without explicitly defining in all the views.
You can also have a look here:**https://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/django-how-to-make-a-variable-available-in-all-templates/**